# Laravel : Too few arguments to function App\Exports\ReportExport::__construct()

Tags: php, laravel

[My error in line 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX5WB.png)

I have imports:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use App\Models\EmployeeInCompany;
use Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
```

And my Export Folder : ReportExport

```
class ReportExport implements FromCollection
{

    use Exportable;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct($request)
    {
       $this->request = $request;
    } 

    public function collection()
    {
        if ($this->request->has('filter_date')) {
            $employee = EmployeeInCompany::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)->get();
        }else{
            $employee = EmployeeInCompany::where('company_id', \Session::get('selected_company'))->get();
        }
    }

}
```

I made an export to excel. I use the code in the public function __construct to hold the $request variable for the date filter. how to solve my problem? help me, thanks.

Comment: ReportController.php isn't passing in a parameter to the constructor. Check your code in that file instead. When you initialize ReportExport you have to pass in the $request value

Comment: Please show us how you are instantiating this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options to handle this:

You can pass the request to your constructor in ReportController.php (make sure $request is defined):

```
new ReportExport($request);
```

or you can remove the parameter in the constructor and use the request helper function:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->request = request();
}
```